# Got a cube when trying to trace a triangle with nvidia raytracing extension

Tags: nvidia, vulkan, raytracing

I am trying to make my first steps with the vulkan raytracing extension from nvidia.

More precisely, I try to trace a simple triangle as a first step to get things going. However, as I expect my code to render a triangle like I want to, somehow a cube is traced and I can't find my mistake.

I think it must have something to do with the creation of my acceleration structures, as the cube gets bigger , when I move the vertices around. Maybe I'm only tracing the top level acceleration structure (maybe the cube is the bounding volume of the triangle?) and ignore the content of the bottom level acceleration structure completely, but I'm not sure about that.

I oriented myself on the vulkan "raytracing basic" example of Sascha Willems. (https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/blob/master/examples/nv_ray_tracing_basic/nv_ray_tracing_basic.cpp) 
In other words, I tried to recreate his code in my own framework.

Therefore, my Expectation to see was the same as the output of his example:
[image]

But my own code produces the discussed cube as follows:

Cube front:
[image]

Cube after slight rotation:
[image]

The red color comes from the closest hit shader. The plan is to take the "in" value for the shader and interpret it as barycentric coordinates to create the desired shading. 
In case of my own code, the value is always the same, as it will produce the same red color each time it is evaluated.

Does anybody have an idea about such a problem?

My source code can be found on github, if someone is interested: https://github.com/mharrer97/saiga/blob/master/src/saiga/vulkan/raytracing/Raytracer.cpp

Comment: Can you also provide a screenshot? Maybe there is no mistake and simply light bounce around.

Comment: @Zydnar thanks for the hint, i added some.